# How do I prevent 'object required' error when referencing a deleted cell?

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I have an issue wherein I need to reference a cell that is deleted during a worksheet_change event. I'm not sure if its even possible, but currently I get most of the way there and then get the object required error because I'm trying to reference the address of something that is no longer there.

My code is looking to get the row address of a cell that is deleted and delete that row in every sheet in the workbook.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Const cCol As String = "A"
Const fRow As Long = 2

Dim crg As Range
Dim ddFound As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim outpt As String

Dim i As Integer

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set crg = Worksheets("Statistics").Columns(cCol).Resize(Rows.Count - fRow + 1).Offset(fRow - 1)
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(crg, Target)
    Dim sraddress As String
    Dim statdel As Range
    
    Set statdel = Sheets("Statistics").Range(irg.Address(0, 0))
    
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim ddcrg As Range
    Dim statrange As Range
    
    sraddress = CStr(irg.Value)
    
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                
                Set ddcrg = ws.Columns(cCol)
                
                Set ddFound = ddcrg.Find(sraddress, , xlValues, xlWhole)
                
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                
                If sraddress <> "" Then
                    
                irg.Select:   ActiveCell = irg.Value2
                
                irg.Copy
                
                ws.Range(irg.Address) = irg.Value2
    
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                
                
                ElseIf sraddress = "" Then
                Sheets(Array("Statistics", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")).Select
                Sheets("Statistics").Activate
                
                Dim Deladdrs As String
                Deladdrs = irg.EntireRow.Address

                
                With Worksheets("Statistics")
                .Range(Deladdrs).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                
                End With
                
                End If
        Next ws
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    
End Sub
```

The part that pops the error up is `Deladdrs = irg.EntireRow.Address` with irg no longer having an object since it gets deleted to fire the worksheet_change event.

Weirdly enough currently the string Deladdrs still populates with the row address of the deleted cell. How do I get the address of the cell that I'm deleting without the error so I can then delete every other row in the workbook on every other sheet with the same cell address?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Place this at the top of your code. This will skip the error and move to the next line of code.